# async pipe show data to late

Tags: angular, firebase, geofirex

I am facing a performance issues with my observable, I am using geofirex to make a search of nearest products :

```
  this.products$ = this.radius.pipe(
    switchMap(r => {
      const firstAds = firebaseApp.firestore().collection('ad').where('state', '==', 'new');
      const defaultOpts: GeoQueryOptions = { units: 'km', log: true };
      return this.geo.query(firstAds).within(this.center, r, this.field, defaultOpts);
    }),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

Geofirex logs show in console that I have received the data, and only 20 seconds later my observable show the data in the template.

Please note that Iam using default changeDetectionStrategy and async pipe to subscribe the observable.

I tried the onPush changeDetectionStrategy and subscribe the observable in the ts and I still have the same issue.

```
  this.products$.subscribe(data => {
    console.log('data', data); // data shown quickly ( 20 sec later in the template)
    this.ads = data;
    this.cd.markForCheck();
  });
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: sounds strange. is 100% of you processor consumed during these 20 seconds?

Comment: I'd say the delay is regarding geofirex and not angular itself. Try to mock the response and return it in the observable instead of making the request to geofirex. You'll then know where the problem resides.